# How to resolve `Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid` error?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, delta-lake

I am trying to create a parquet file in an ALDS gen2 container but it is failing with below error

`Status code 400, "{"error":{"code":"InvalidQueryParameterValue","message":"Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.\nRequestId:0dec0224-c01f-0048-5227-36ecfc000000\nTime:2023-02-01T10:23:08.8603292Z"}}"`

Below is the code snippet I am using to create a file:

```
public void uploadFile(File fileToUpload) {
    StorageSharedKeyCredential sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential("adlssynapse123","accountKey");

    DataLakeServiceClientBuilder builder = new DataLakeServiceClientBuilder();
    DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient =
            builder.credential(sharedKeyCredential).endpoint(endpoint).buildClient(); 

    DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient = dataLakeServiceClient.getFileSystemClient("hdfs");

    DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient =fileSystemClient.getDirectoryClient("synapse/workspaces/adls-synapse/warehouse/adlstesting");

    DataLakeFileClient fileClient = directoryClient.createFile(fileToUpload.getName()); // This is where the execution fails

    fileClient.uploadFromFile(fileToUpload.getPath());
}
```

can some please help resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Status code 400, "{"error":{"code":"InvalidQueryParameterValue","message":"Value for one of the query parameters specified in the request URI is invalid.\nRequestId:0dec0224-c01f-0048-5227 36ecfc000000\nTime:2023-02-01T10:23:08.8603292Z"}}"

The above error indicates one of the query parameters specified on the request URI is Invalid.

The issue is likely with the `"fileToUpload.getName()`" argument provided to the "createFile" method, as that is where the execution fails. Verify if the value of fileToUpload.getName() is a valid file name and identifies the API's requirements.

To create parquet file and upload in ADLS Gen 2 you can refer the below sample code:

**Code:**

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
    {
     StorageSharedKeyCredential sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential("Straccountname","<Account key>");
     DataLakeServiceClientBuilder builder = new DataLakeServiceClientBuilder();
     DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient =builder
     .credential(sharedKeyCredential)
     .endpoint("https://Straccountname.dfs.core.windows.net")
     .buildClient(); 
     DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient = dataLakeServiceClient.getFileSystemClient("test");
     DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient =fileSystemClient.getDirectoryClient("synapse/workspaces");
     DataLakeFileClient fileClient = directoryClient.getFileClient("demo.parquet");
     fileClient.uploadFromFile("<filepath>");
  
    }
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Use Java to manage data in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-java)